# GSON, @SerializedName not taken into account when class is loaded in different scope

Tags: scope, annotations, gson, javabeans, portlet

I have created two exactly the same classes in two different packages and two different .jars. the com.test is loaded globally (placed in /lib/ext/) in Tomcat7, while es.package is loaded as a dependency of a portlet.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class RequestBean implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("SOMETHING")
    private String  id;

    @SerializedName("CUENTA")
    private String  account;

    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When having the following code in the portlet:

```
com.test.RequestBean localBean = new com.test.RequestBean();
localBean.setAccount("account");
localBean.setId("100");

es.package.RequestBean globalBean = new es.package.RequestBean();
globalBean.setAccount("account");
globalBean.setId("100");

System.out.println(gson.toJson(localBean, localBean.getClass()).toString());
System.out.println(gson.toJson(globalBean, globalBean.getClass()).toString());
```

To my surprise, the result is different. For the globalBean @SerializedName is not taken into account. What can be the reason that? Global class is available in the global scope and the local one only for the scope of a portlet.

```
{"SOMETHING":"100","CUENTA":"account"} 
{"id":"100","account":"account"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was gson-2.2.0 loaded in the scope of portlet and gson-3.2.1 in the global. Leaving just the global one fixed this issue.